# Cost of running create function if not exists foo() in Snowflke if the function already exists?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What is the cost of running
`create function if not exists foo()`
if the function already exists?

In Snowflake Query History it doesn't show any warehouse on the entry.

Comment: Given that even if there was a cost it would be minuscule, why do you care?

Comment: @NickW I am using the on-run-start in dbt to create the required functions if they don't exist. Since on-run-start get kicked off every time a new dbt job starts, I want to make sure there is no to `create function if not exists foo()` if the function already exists.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is....probably nothing.  The long answer is that this is a Cloud Services cost on Snowflake, which is more easily explained here:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/cost-understanding-compute#label-cloud-services-credit-usage

In Snowflake query history, you won't see a warehouse on the entry, because it didn't use one.  That's how you know it is a Cloud Services cost, rather than a warehouse cost.